# $X_1,..,X_n$ i.i.d random variable and discrete, local limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

> Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be i.i.d discrete random variables which take their value in $\mathbb{Z}$ with a non trivial and finite support. Let $S_n = X_1+...+ X_n$
>
> Prove the existence of $ 0 < C_1 < C_2 < \infty$ such that for all $ n \geq 1$ :
>
> $$ C_1/\sqrt{n} \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}(S_n = k) \leq C_2/\sqrt{n}$$

I know that this can be proved using the central limit theorem yet we didn’t see this theorem in class so this exercise can be solved without using CLT.

So far here are my thoughts :

The fact that it’s $\sqrt{n}$ comes from the fact that the standard deviation of $S_n$ is $\theta \sqrt{n}$.
Hence one possible strategy is to study the random variable :
$\frac{S_n- \mu}{\theta/\sqrt{n}}$. Yet from now on I dind’t manage finding an upper bound on the probability.

For example using Markov inequality I get that :

$$\mathbb{P}( \mid \frac{S_n}{n} -\mu \mid \geq \theta/\sqrt{n}) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

The problem is that it doesn’t help since I can’t say anything when $\mid S_n/n -\mu \mid \leq \theta/\sqrt{n}$.

Thank you !

Comment: You can apply your Markov/Chebyshev inequality if you know the random variables have a finite variance (else you might need some type of truncation argument).  That inequality you give is useful since there is an order-$\sqrt{n}$ region about the mean such that we are there with probability at least $1/2$.  And of course we must always be an integer.

Comment: @Michael Yes you are right about variance, so it’s even harder to prove iron the general case (when we don’t necessarily have variance). Yet I still don’t see how to prove it when we have variance.

Comment: You can just try to get one of the bounds at first (either the lower or upper).  For example, what happens when most of the probability is concentrated on only a few of the options?  Say, if probability $p$ is spread over $k$ options, there must be some option with at least...

Comment: I don’t think this is true without extra conditions such as finite variance.  For intuition with continuous variables, if $\{X_i\}$ are iid Cauchy random variables with PDF $f(x)$ then the average $S_n/n$ is Cauchy with the same PDF. So \begin{align}P[S_n \in [a,a+1]] &= P[S_n/n \in [a/n, a/n+1/n]]\\ &= \int_{a/n}^{a/n+1/n} f(x)dx \\&\leq \frac{f_{max}}{n} = O(1/n)\end{align} Likely a "discrete Cauchy-type" random variable would have similar $O(1/n)$ behavior.

Comment: @Jebfiffkkfnfolzbd What exactly does “non-trivial support” mean? It seems that $X_k$'s can be unbounded.

Comment: @Saad I guess it means that $V(X) \ne 0$.

Comment: @Saad It means that there isn’t an event $x \in \Omega$ such that : $P(X=x) =1$. Also I am sorry but I forgot to say that the support is finite (ie. $X(\Omega) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Michael I am so sorry I forgot to say that the support is finite ($X(\Omega) \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @Jebfiffkkfnfolzbd : $X(\Omega)$ is the set of all real numbers that $X$ can take, and it is always  a subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ (for any random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$).   By "finite support" I think you mean that $X$ can only take a value from some finite interval $[a,b]$. This means that it indeed has a finite mean and variance.  Since we also know that $X$ is integer valued, it means that $X$ can only take a finite number of (integer) values.

Comment: @Michael Yes of course I meant $\mid X(\Omega) \mid \in \mathbb{R}$. But do you have a solution with finite variance ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, the lower bound comes directly from the Markov/Chebyshev inequality $$P[|S_n- n \mu| > 2\sigma\sqrt{n}] \leq \frac{n\sigma^2}{4\sigma^2 n} = 1/4$$ For example if you have a total probability of $p$ spread over $k$ disjoint events: $$\{S_n = val_1\}, \{S_n=val_2\}, ...\{S_n=val_k\}$$ then there must be at least one event with a probability at least...

Answer (score 1):

I can prove the lower bound as follows:

$P(|S_n-n\mu| \geq cn^a\theta) \leq \frac{1}{c^2n^{2a-1}}$.

Thus the largest $P(S_n=k)$ is roughly greater than $(1-c^{-2}n^{1-2a})(2cn^a\theta+1)^{-1}$. 
(Because this quantity is not greater than $P(|S_n-n\mu| \leq cn^a\theta)|[n\mu-cn^a\theta,n\mu+cn^a\theta] \cap \mathbb{Z}|^{-1}$).

Take $a=1/2, c=2$, this quantity is greater than $\frac{3/4}{4\theta\sqrt{n}+1}$, which proves the lower bound.

Edit: this was done without looking at Michael’s comment.